# How to set a line border around JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I have a `JTextArea` in my panel, but it is hard to distinguish it from the background.
I tried `setBound()` but it doesn't really help.
Screenshot of my GUI

[image]

(The textarea is next to 
the 'DESCRIPTION')

Is there any way to have a clear bound around it other than changing the colour of the background? Say having a line bound like what `JTextField` has(I put one next to 'EXPENSE' in my GUI).

Comment: You probably want to set border. Setting bounds has nothing to do with it. For more help post [mre].

Comment: There are at least two ways to get a line around the text area. 1) Put it in a `JSCrollPane` 2) Add a `LineBorder`.

Comment: C.f. [How To Use Borders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html)  As mentioned the LineBorder is probably the simplest and will do what you want.

Comment: Make sure you put it in a JScrollPane

Comment: Forgot to mention: The GUI looks like it is using a `GridLayout` which results in making all the components (as well as the labels) the same size. Since most of the label space is invisible, it makes little difference to them, but it screws up the look of text field and combo boxes, making them unusually large. Use a 'GridBagLayout` instead. It will only assign as much space as needed for the component (using a standard `GridBagConstraints`).

Comment: @c0der Thank you for the remainder, I have edited my question title to set border. Do I need to do anything else with my question?

Comment: I would recommend to either make it useful to future readers by answering your own question (all the **update** part of your post should be posted as an answer rather than an edit to the question). Or delete the question all together.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thank you so much for your suggestion about using `GridBagLayout` instead. It saves me lots of time for my later work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the guys in the comment area! I put the textarea into a JScrollpane. It does create a border:

[using JScrollPane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSUdz.png)

Then I also added a line border to make it more clear.

```
des.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
```

Thanks again to Andrew Thompson, the suggestion about using `GridBagLayout` does make everything look much better.

[Using GridBagLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UehOq.png)

Comment: Good one for taking the suggestions and implementing them. Congrats on finding a solution.